# EF Code First. Related Entity is not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I've got Entity Framework Code First Entities:

```
public class Customer
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<ServiceAccount> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceAccount
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
   [Required()]
   public Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

It is supposed that a Customer has some Accounts for the Services. But there can be some default Accounts, which are not bounded to any Customer. And each Account is used for a concrete Service.
This Entities have the following Configuration:

```
// Customer Configuration:
base.ToTable("Customers");
base.HasKey(x => x.Id);
base.HasMany(x => x.ServiceAccounts)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Customer)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
// For Service:
base.ToTable("Services");
base.HasKey(x => x.Id);
// For Account:
base.ToTable("Accounts");
base.HasKey(x => x.Id);
base.HasOptional(x => x.Customer)
    .WithMany(x => x.Accounts);
base.HasRequired(x => x.Service)
    .WithMany();
```

The problem is, when I load a Customer, all his Accounts are loaded too, but they have their Service set to null. Why it is not loaded?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you loading the customers - could this be an eager vs lazy loading issue? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Show us the code where you get the data.

Comment: I load them like this:
IQueryable<Customer> customers = Customers.Include(x => x.Accounts);
How can I include Accounts' Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the entities. Based on your comment:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = Customers.Include(x => x.Accounts.Select(y => y.Service));
```

They should also be `virtual` if you want proxies for lazy loading... but for eager loading it's not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading of related entities requires the framework to create a proxy of your entity. Try making your navigation properties virtual:

```
public class ServiceAccount
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, eager-load the properties with `Include` or you can even explicitly load them with `Load`.

For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Making them virtual did not help.